# Vertically center DIV inside LI without px-measure

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a list with square bullets in different colors with square size independant of the font size.

I need to use font sizes in em or %.

That's my best try so far: http://jsfiddle.net/3GMjp/29/

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
        <span class='li_box green'></span>
        <span>Element 1</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
        <span class='li_box red'></span>
        <span>Element 2</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
        <span class='li_box blue'></span>
        <span>Element 3</span>
    </div>
  </li>
<ul>
```

css:

```
ul { 
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

li { 
    font-size: 1.5em; 
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height: 2em;
}

.li_box {
        float:left;
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:10px;
}

.red{ background-color:red}
.green{ background-color:green}
.blue{ background-color:blue}
```

Could someone help me to center the boxes without adding px-measures?

Any working solution (would be appreciated)!

Comment: is my answer work for you? See it in fiddle.

Comment: I just recognized i mixed vertical with horizontal! I obviously ment center vertical. Sorry and thank you all for the answers so far. Could you please have another look?

Answer (score 1):

See I have done modification in the `CSS` and `HTML` :

Please see URL : http://jsfiddle.net/3GMjp/33/

**HTML code:**

```
   <li>
        <div>
            <span class='li_box green'></span>
            <span class='spn'>Element 1</span>
        </div>
    </li>
```

**CSS changes :**

```
ul { 
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

li { 
    font-size: 1.5em; 
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height: 2em;
}

li div { 
    display:table;
}
.spn{ 
    display:table-cell;
}

.li_box {
        display:table-cell;
        float:left;
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:10px;
}

.red{ background-color:red}
.green{ background-color:green}
.blue{ background-color:blue}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3GMjp/674/).
If you float an element, it will become a block element, and thus vertical align won't work. The span with the text, unless floated as well, will wrap to the next line.

Inline block seems to work just fine:

```
.li_box {
        display: inline-block;
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
        margin-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking to center the content of the `div`s, this should be all you need:

```
 div { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: I think he is talking about vertical align not horizontal :-)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
li { 
   ...
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: This is horizontal align, op wanted vertical align

Comment: @Scott first time I seen this Q, its title had "Horizontal" word!

Answer (score 0):

Adding margin top to `.li_box` will fix your issue.

```
.li_box {
...
margin-top: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not :( It's still not centered vertically.